# Simplifying multiple Application.Wait in VBA

Tags: function, vba, variables, wait

I've researched for an answer to my problem. I'm a newbie, though I'm picking up really fast.

I want to do something like this:

```
Sub name()
    Dim waitOne As Date (or Variant?)
    waitOne = Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    Selection.Copy
        waitOne 'second
    Application.SendKeys "%{Tab}", True 'switching to another application
        waitOne 'second
    Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
End Sub
```

Or replace waitOne with the following declaration

```
 Sub name()

    Function waitSec()
  waitOne = Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
     End Function

    Selection.Copy
        waitSec() 'second
    Application.SendKeys "%{Tab}", True
        waitSec() 'second
    Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
End Sub
```

neither of which works. I'm looking to simplfy coding for a cleaner look and easier to read. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You cannot nest methods in VBA - move `WaitSec` outside of `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Application.Wait to wait for 1 second is highly unreliable as its time resolution is only itself in the order of 1 second. This is in addition to the errors in the syntax of your original code (as you realised).

For short delays, use Sleep from kernel32:

Use it like:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub mySub()
    Sleep 500 'pauses execution for at least 500 milliseconds
End Sub
```

So, , use the above for a much simpler and more reliable sleep :)

Edit: just so you realise, you do not define a function inside a sub, you do it outside - like:

```
Sub mySub()
    MsgBox myFunc()
End Sub
Function myFunc()
    myFunc = "Hello!"
End Function
```

Comment: ***oh gosh, sorry for bad formatting here***

I tried that, and for some reason, it's pasting only values from the previous column 'Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) Sub waitOne() Sleep 500 'pauses execution for at least 500 milliseconds End Sub Sub NavTest() <copy and paste commands> waitOne() <commands> End sub'

Comment: that is not related to the question of Application.Wait, but anyway - I don't think SendKeys can be used to interact with **another** application. You need to use shell - it is a bit more complex. I suggest you post that part of your problem (how to send keys to a different application) as a seperate question then you should get a response that is relevant to that issue.

Comment: I'm not worried about SendKeys, what I'm focused on is creating variable or function to do something specific for waiting/sleeping. Say, I want to do "waitSeconds(5)" to do five seconds.

Comment: so then what is the problem? Anything to do with "pasting values from the previous column" is nothing to do with how to wait/sleep ;). You don't need a sub for it - simple call `Sleep x` where x is number of milliseconds you want to wait for. E.g. for a 5 seconds sleep call `Sleep 5000`

Comment: The pasting into the next column should NOT be happening. It should be pasting into another application. This issue didn't happen until I used I tried the suggestions. I tried commenting out to see if they were the issue, but the problem still persists. I will report back later to see if I can get it to work again. In any case, thank you, once I have this problem fixed, I'll try 'Sleep #' in the test code. :)

Comment: Okay, figured it out. Macro unmapped the hotkey. I mapped Ctrl+r for the test code. In any case, Sleep will do nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @user3590420 you're welcome - glad you got it sorted. Please consider marking my answer as "Accepted"

Comment: The more I tried this out, I've run into problems. Sleep is freezing up Excel (white screen overlayed the program). Anyway, I thought I did accept the answer? I cannot see images because of vision impairment and there's no easy wayy to tell. I "blindly" pressed something abvoe the number zero.

Comment: what number did you pass in to Sleep?

Comment: I tried 500, then 1500, 1000, 2500... 'Sleep 500' and so on.